How to get the all the target features rustc is using (like we get from gcc -v)
I'd like to see what all the target specific flags are used by rust. e.g.,
$ gcc -v a.c -c -march=native

 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu a.c -march=znver2 -mmmx -mpopcnt -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mavx -mavx2 -msse4a -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mfma -mno-avx512f -mbmi -mbmi2 -maes -mpclmul -mno-avx512vl -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512pf -mno-avx512vbmi -mno-avx512ifma -mno-avx5124vnniw -mno-avx5124fmaps -mno-avx512vpopcntdq -mno-avx512vbmi2 -mno-gfni -mno-vpclmulqdq -mno-avx512vnni -mno-avx512bitalg -mno-avx512bf16 -mno-avx512vp2intersect -mno-3dnow -madx -mabm -mno-cldemote -mclflushopt -mclwb -mclzero -mcx16 -mno-enqcmd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mfxsr -mno-hle -msahf -mno-lwp -mlzcnt -mmovbe -mno-movdir64b -mno-movdiri -mmwaitx -mno-pconfig -mno-pku -mno-prefetchwt1 -mprfchw -mno-ptwrite -mrdpid -mrdrnd -mrdseed -mno-rtm -mno-serialize -mno-sgx -msha -mno-shstk -mno-tbm -mno-tsxldtrk -mno-vaes -mno-waitpkg -mwbnoinvd -mxsave -mxsavec -mxsaveopt -mxsaves -mno-amx-tile -mno-amx-int8 -mno-amx-bf16 -mno-uintr -mno-hreset -mno-kl -mno-widekl -mno-avxvnni -mno-avx512fp16 -mno-avxifma -mno-avxvnniint8 -mno-avxneconvert -mno-cmpccxadd -mno-amx-fp16 -mno-prefetchi -mno-raoint -mno-amx-complex --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=512 -mtune=znver2 -quiet -dumpbase a.c -dumpbase-ext .c -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -o /tmp/ccpEUbXQ.s

From the gcc's output I can know what all the target specific flags were used (e.g., -march=znver2 -mavx2 -msse4a etc). rustc prints nothing.
$ rustc a.rs -C target-cpu=native -v
$ RUSTFLAGS="-C -v -C link-arg=-Wl,--verbose" rustc a.rs -C target-cpu=native -v 


The full invocation of what exactly?

I'd like to know the target features rustc is using to build a binary.

Updated the title, it was confusing.
